# How to create a model instance object in Django without a form

Tags: django, django-models

New to django here. I am following this documentation link to create an instance of a model
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/instances/#creating-objects and I am missing something. Here is my code

```
#models.py
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    @classmethod
    def create(cls, title):
        print('print title:')
        print(title)
        book = cls(title=title)
        # do something with the book
        return book

#forms.py
book = Book.create("Pride and Prejudice")
print('printing DJANGO--------------')
print(book)

#console output
print title:
Pride and Prejudice
printing DJANGO--------------
Book object (None)
```

I have literally copied the code from the tutorial and haven't changed a thing. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Have you done the official tutorial ? If not, you should, really - the API reference is indeed the most important part of the doc, but definitly not the best entry point ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is okay from my point of view. Just add `book.save()` and you'll see an id instead of `None`

If you want to change model's human readability, just add [**str**()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.__str__) method to model

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```